# Regex: match all non-digits except commas and '-' sign

Tags: regex

I want to remove all non-digits from a string, except not the commas and the minus signs. What would be the right regex for this?

example:
'Euro 16.000' => '16000'
'Euro 16,00' => '16,00'
'Euro -16,00' => '-16,00'

Comment: How about using a negated class: Replace [`[^\d,-]+` with empty](https://regex101.com/r/XaNHJP/1) string (in demo also contains `\n` for not skipping lines).

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work assuming there will always be numbers to the left and right of the decimal point/comma

```
reg = /[-]?[0-9]{0,}[.]?[,]?[0-9]{1,}/
s = 'euro -16,000'
s = reg.exec(s)[0]
reg = /[0-9]{1}[.]{1}[0-9]{1}/
matched = reg.exec(s)
if (matched) {
    s = s.replace(reg, matched[0][0]+matched[0][2])
}
// s == '-16,000'
```